# jQuery for parsing XML

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing

```
         <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>MyTitle</title></channel></rss>";
            var data = $.parseXML(xml);
            console.log(data);
            $(data).find('rss').each(function(){
            var name = $(this).attr('version');
            $('<div class="items"></div>').html('<a href="'+name+'"></a>').appendTo('#page-wrap');
            });
        });
    </script>
<body>
    <div id="page-wrap">
        </div>
</body>
```

What is wrong with the above code? I just get a blank page. It is not going even beyond the var data declaration.

EDIT: Now I am passing the correct xml to parseXML() but still not result. What else is missing?

EDIT2: Any idea why below code does not display any output on Chrome browser? Though the script and the html code when put in JSFiddle produces the correct result.

EDIT3: Using jquery-1.9.0 made it work. Thanks everyone for your help and support.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">

$(document).ready(function(){
            var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>MyTitle</title></channel></rss>";
            var data = $.parseXML(xml);
            console.log(data);
            $(data).find('rss').each(function(){
            var name = $(this).attr('version');
            $('<div class="items"></div>').html('<a href="'+name+'">'+name+'</a>').appendTo('#page-wrap');
            });
        });

     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page-wrap"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: Console Error: Uncaught TypeError: Object function (selector,context){return this instanceof jQuery?this.init(selector,context):new jQuery(selector,context);} has no method 'parseXML'

Comment: i dont see 'method' in your xml so find doesnt return anything. Or this is some dummy xml you posted here? Using your code and changing 'method' to 'title' (for example) and using $(this).text() inside loop i was being able to set href for link to 'MyTitle'. Btw your link name is also empty.

Comment: sorry i used a dummy xml. Corrected it.

Comment: it works if you set link title (in corrected code you still dont have it). [See](http://jsfiddle.net/uxM4Y/).

Comment: when I open it with Chrome it gives me this error - Uncaught TypeError: Object function (selector,context){return this instanceof jQuery?this.init(selector,context):new jQuery(selector,context);} has no method 'parseXML'

Comment: what jQuery version you included in your project?

Comment: Ok I messed up the jQuery inclusion. It runs now in Chrome. But where do you see the output? I don't see anything in Chrome console.

Comment: in console tab of chrome development tool (f12).

Comment: I see blank console in Chrome (f12) for your code. Again am I missing anything?

Comment: i dont know, console is fine in jsFiddle example i posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it little wrong.

1. You are looking for the node `method` which actually doesn't exists in the xml.
2. What is the attr('name')? To whom does it belong to?
3. `<a>` tag does have the text to show as a link. E.g. `<a href="url">The Text</a>`
4. Lastly, since you are appending the  (wrapped in a ), I simplified your code.

Follow the following fiddle: [JS Fiddle to your code](http://jsfiddle.net/VWP8C/3/)

Answer (score 3):

see [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/). Input to  `parseXML` should be a well formed xml string and not a file location

Answer (score 2):

your browser process is not able to directly open files from your file system, it would be an easily exploitable security hole if it could.

Comment: +1, but note that browsers mostly have an option in their settings to allow local Filesystem access. But this would only be applicable if you are deploying your web-app inside an intranet, and that you would batch-configure all the computers in that network. This is often common practice in universities and companies internally.

Comment: Whatever, file system locations need to start with `file:`.